# How to build .apk file from mozilla fennec build instructions

Tags: android, android-ndk-r5, fennec

I have tried to build Mozilla Fennec browser for Android. I have followed [the instructions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Fennec/Android). It doesn't show any issue until the `make` instruction:

> make -f client.mk build_and_deploy

It stops at `make -C . fast-package` instruction since the compiler couldn't recognize fast package instruction. So I have continued without `fast-package` option. Again it stopped at

```
if test -d ./dist/bin ; then touch ./dist/bin/.purgecaches ; fi
```

> make: Leaving directory `/home/user/android/src/config'

`/dist/*.apk` is not created in the `/objdir-droid` folder. mozconfig paths are correct. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

fwiw

if test -d ./dist/bin ; then touch ./dist/bin/.purgecaches ; fi

means a build finished successfully. use build_and_deploy with your device attached via USB

Comment: I didn't find  the build in the mentioned directory